# The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.201\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found

Tags: visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017, I go to the Package Manager to do a dotnet restore.
Then I get an error message

> error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.201\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"
>   was not found.

I navigate to

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.201\Microsoft

and the VisualStudio path is missing and hence the error message. How do I fix this?

Comment: I just started seeing this today too.

Comment: I get this error on the command line, but not from within Visual Studio. Driving me nuts.

Comment: Hi there, you can try this workaround:
https://github.com/dotnet-websharper/core/issues/903

Comment: Does your solution contain mixed .NET Framework/.NET Core projects by any chance?

Comment: @Vivelin Yes it does, I suspect that might be a good question.

Answer (score 17):

If you have a mixed solution that contains both .NET Framework and .NET Core (web) projects, `dotnet restore` won't be able to build .NET Framework projects and will cause an error in newer versions of the .NET Core SDK, as detailed in [NuGet/Home#6665](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6665#issuecomment-380572274).

If you are experiencing this error from the command line, but not from Visual Studio itself, you might have more luck building the full solution using MSBuild.